# Not able to install SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, errors

I am installing SQL Server however I'm getting following errors.
[image]

[image]

Has anyone else encountered similar errors before? If so what's the fix?

Comment: Do you have any backup software running?

Comment: No, we don't have any backup of the software running.

Comment: Not backup of the software. Software which *runs* backups. Like Veeam or Acronis

Comment: Hey sorry for the misunderstanding. But no we don't have anything like that running.

Comment: If it’s Windows 11, try this https://www.koder.ly/2022/05/windows-11-sql-server-error-database-engine/

Comment: @FrugalShaun no it's not windows 11, it's a Windows 2016 Server. Although, I did try out the solution you mentioned above but it didn't work.